# if condition for java sikuli is not working

Tags: java, testing, automation, sikuli, sikuli-x

I am writing scripts using Java-sikuli, and trying to use *if condition* as follows:

```
if(screen.exists(gameIsInProgress) != null || 
   screen.exists(waitingFormorePlayer) !=null) {
        screen.click(settingsOnGameWindow);
        screen.click(exitRoom);
        screen.click(yes);
}
```

I am checking whether the image exists, and if - yes, then I click some buttons. The issue is, even if the image does not exist it is searching for that button, which is causing the test to fail.

Answer (score 1):

RaiMan from SikuliX:

Maybe you have to use a higher score for the images.
Check with the SikuliX IDE Preview feature.

This might happen, if the image (e.g. gameIsInProgress) is always visible, but changes its state with respect to color.

Comment: hi Raiman, thanks alot for the answer,                                                                             Maybe you have to use a higher score for the images. => I didnt understand this point could you please verify.                                                                                                     
 This might happen, if the image (e.g. gameIsInProgress) is always visible, but changes its state with respect to color. => this is not the case and I tried with a case where the image was not visible it is happening with all the if conditions.

Comment: Instead of exists(gameIsInProgress) use exists(Pattern(gameIsInProgress).similar(0.9)). An appropriate value for the wanted similarity can be found using the SikuliX's Preview feature.

Comment: Pratiksha Dalal, I guess that Raiman is talking about the feature of the Sikuli called image similarity. Where to find Image similarity - follow the steps below
1. Grab an image
2. Click on the image
3. On the second tab (Matching preview) find a slider below the image
4. Observe what sikuli 'see' on the screen, may image similar to yours was found by sikuli which is not so obvious for the human eye.

I hope this help!